# identifying RAM rank of a 32gb PC4-2400 DIMM

Tags: memory

have a RAM DIMM, sticker says `samsung 32GB 2Rx4 PC4-2400T-RA1-11-DC0` and I believe the model number is `M393A4K40BB1-CRC0Q S`

The dimm has chips on both sides, and on a given side it is 2 rows with 5 columns of chips on left and 4 columns of chips on the right; so 18 chips on one side and another 18 chips on the other side.

Is this specific dimm single rank, dual rank, or quad rank?  And is there a simple way to visually tell?

The server it goes in has a total of 96 DIMM slots, using 32gb dimms it was running 3.0TB of RAM.  For these types of servers today how important is single, dual, or quad rank and why?

*when you're dealing with 32gb, 64gb, or 128gb DIMM's now with 24, 48, or uo to 96 DIMM slots, how does single/dual/quad rank come into context?  I ask because I thought the "memory controller" can only access so many ranks so 96 dimms at quad rank = too many need dual rank or single rank  ?*

*also looking to gain a better understanding putting all this into context with 32gb dimms or larger that is 288 pin DDR4.*

Comment: here is an accurate pic of what i am asking about, it is the **BOTTOM** pic on this page: https://www.serversupply.com/MEMORY/PC4-19200/32GB/SAMSUNG/M393A4K40BB1-CRC4Q.htm

Comment: It's Dual Rank.

Comment: and at that page **it shows 2 different listings with 2 different pics** both of which are `SAMSUNG M393A4K40BB1-CRC4Q 32GB (1X32GB) 2400MHZ PC4-19200 CL17 ECC REGISTERED DUAL RANK X4 1.2V DDR4 SDRAM 288-PIN RDIMM`.  thus my question... *i realize they say image may not exactly match product*

Comment: It tells you right in the description: Dual Rank.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/dram/module/M393A4K40BB1-CRC/

This shows more detailed info about the memory module. The 2R means it is a dual rank module.